# Question about embeddings of connected sum of manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

If $M_j,j=1,2$are smooth manifolds and we have two embeddings $i_j:M_j\to\mathbf{R}^k(j=1,2)$(with $k$ fixed). How can we construct a embedding of the connected sum $M_1\sharp M_2$ into $\mathbf{R}^k$? 
For definition of "connected sum", see:
Section 10(pp.98) of TH.Brocker & K.Jaenich, Introduction to Differential Topology Cambridge Univ.Press.
Thanks!